# Apple Fairplay TVML can't get AssetId, certificate and key

Tags: ios, drm, tvml, fairplay

After spending many days on search on google about how to use Fairplay in TVML (Apple TV), i can't get this work.

I am trying to use Apple FairPlay using TVML, there is no clear documentation or example that can help for integration.

in my code on singleVideo.loadCertificate function i am trying to get the assetId, but it's keep calling the same function with out errors

```
singleVideo.loadAssetID = function(url, callback) {
        console.log("===== HERE === ");  
        console.log("======== loadAssetID=======");
        console.log(url);

        var extractContentId = function (initData) {

            var uri = initData;
            var uriParts = uri.split('://');
            var protocol = uriParts[0].slice(-3);
            var contentId = uriParts.length > 0 ? uriParts[1] : '';
            return protocol.toLowerCase() == 'skd' ? contentId : '';
        };

        asset=extractContentId(url);
        var error=null;
        console.log("->AssetID="+ asset);

        callback(btoa(asset));
    }

    singleVideo.loadCertificate = function(url, callback) {

        console.log("==== Getting the certificate");  

        var certUrl = "cer url";  

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';  
        request.addEventListener('load', function () {
            console.log( "RESPONSE ");
            console.log( request.getAllResponseHeaders () );
            console.log( request.response );
            var base64 = btoa(new Uint8Array(request.response)
                .reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
            );
            callback( base64);

        }, false);  
        request.addEventListener('error', function (error) {
            console.log(error)}
        , false);  


        request.open('GET', certUrl, true);  
        request.setRequestHeader('Pragma', 'Cache-Control: no-cache');  
        request.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");  
        request.send();  


    }

    singleVideo.loadKey = function(url, requestData, callback) {
        console.log("======= [FPS] getting the FPS asset key");  


        var assetID = asset;  
        var postBody = "payload=" + base64EncodeUint8Array(requestData) + "&id=" + base64EncodeUint8Array(assetID);  

        var keyUrl = "server key url";  
        console.log("======= [FPS] keyurl: " + keyUrl + " sending " + postBody);  


        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.responseType = 'text';
        request.addEventListener('load', function(){
            console.log(request);
            callback(request.responseText, null, null);
        }, false);
        request.addEventListener('error', function(){
            console.log(request);
            callback(null, null, "Got bad response from server: " + request.status)
        }, false);
        request.open('POST', keyUrl, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send(postBody);
    }
```

can anyone help me with integration and tell me where is the error in my code?

Comment: Did you find the answer ?

Comment: @Ajq no not yet

Comment: Did you find the solution?